# Unity game doesn't respond to touches

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have an Android game where user moves player by touching left and right side of the screen. I tried the game on Android and all worked OK. But one day it stopped working: buttons work but I can't control the Player by touching screen sides. I tried to reinstall Unity, delete Library folder and even tried other OS. It didn't help. How can I fix my project?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MovingPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float playerSpeed;
    public float maxPos = 2.7f;

    Vector3 position;
    public uiManager ui;
    public AudioManager am;

    public Text coinCount;

    int coin;

    bool currntPlatformAndroid = false;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    public GameObject particleSystemPrefab;

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

#if UNITY_ANDROID
        currntPlatformAndroid = true;
#else
                currentPlatformAndroid = false;
#endif

        am.playerSound.Play();

    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        coin = 0;
        position = transform.position;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (currntPlatformAndroid == true)
        {
            TouchMove();
            //AccelerometerMove();
        }

        else
        {

            position.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -2.7f, 2.7f);

            transform.position = position;
        }

        position = transform.position;
        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -2.7f, 2.7f);

        transform.position = position;

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "CubeObstacle")
        {
            //Destroy (gameObject);
            foreach (ContactPoint2D contact in col.contacts)
            {
                Instantiate(particleSystemPrefab, contact.point, Quaternion.identity);

            }
            //gameObject.SetActive(false);

            GameOverActivated();
            ui.gameOverActivated();
            am.playerSound.Stop();
        }

        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            coin += 1;
            coinCount.text = coin.ToString();

            Debug.Log("Coin");
        }

    }

    public void GameOverActivated()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins") + coin);
    }


    void AccelerometerMove()
    {
        float x = Input.acceleration.x;

        if (x < -0.1f)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }

        else if (x > 0.1f)
        {
            MoveRight();
        }

        else
        {
            SetVelocityZero();
        }
    }

    void TouchMove()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            float middle = Screen.width / 2;

            if (touch.position.x < middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                MoveLeft();
            }

            else if (touch.position.x > middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                MoveRight();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SetVelocityZero();
        }
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-playerSpeed, 0);
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(playerSpeed, 0);
    }

    public void SetVelocityZero()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: People need to see your code to help.. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: OK. I added the code.

Comment: It looks like there will only be one frame where the phase is TouchBegan - all other frames will call SetVelocityZero, cancelling the movement

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Input.Touches`, this should work fine:

```
void Update()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        position.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -2.7f, 2.7f);

        transform.position = position;
    #else
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width/2)
            {
                MoveRight();
            }
            else
            {
                MoveLeft()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SetVelocityToZero();
        }

    #endif
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: On mobile devices, always use `Input.Touches`.  This question is about Android. `Input.GetMouseButton` and `Input.mousePosition` should not be used for that.

Comment: That's right. However, in this specific scenario, `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` and `Input.MousePosition` works perfect as only one touch interaction is allowed to steer/move in left right direction. In other cases where 'Input.Touches' should be used.